# How to move a sprite (image) across a JFrame window?

Tags: java, swing, sprite, pixel

I'm having some issue moving an image across a `JFrame` window. Here is how the code looks:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

Image caitlanImage = new ImageIcon("Caitlan.png").getImage();
Person caitlan = new Person(caitlanImage, "Caitlan", 10, 200, true);

Person jake;
Image jakeImage;

//Background images
Image granadaBackground;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    new Main();
}
public Main() throws InterruptedException{
    setSize(700,300);
    setTitle("Project Anniversary");
    setVisible(true);   
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addKeyListener(this);

    //Instantiate background images
    granadaBackground = new ImageIcon("Granada Background.jpg").getImage();

    //Spawn first background
    spawnBackground(granadaBackground);

    //Spawn initial sprite
    spawnSprite(caitlan);
}

public void moveSprite(Person p) throws InterruptedException{   //Method to move a         
sprite 10 pixels (BROKEN)
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        p.setLocation(p.getPosX() + 10, p.getPosY());
        g.drawImage(caitlan.getImage(), caitlan.getPosX() + 10,     
caitlan.getPosY(), caitlan.getImage().getWidth(null), caitlan.getImage().getHeight(null), 
null);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){   //Overridden paint method

}
public void spawnSprite(Person p){  //Method to initially spawn a sprite
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(p.getImage(), p.getPosX(), p.getPosY(), 
            p.getImage().getWidth(null), p.getImage().getHeight(null), null);
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { //Method called whenever a key is pressed
    if(e.getKeyChar() == new String("d").charAt(0)){
        try {
            moveSprite(caitlan);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

        }
    }
}
public void spawnBackground(Image backgroundImage){
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, backgroundImage.getWidth(null),    
backgroundImage.getHeight(null),null);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   //IGNORE

}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {      //IGNORE

}

}
```

What is meant to happen here is whenever the "d" key is pressed, the sprite moves 10 pixels right. However, what ends up happening is that it is repainted 10 pixels left, and the original image still remains, so it looks like a fairly disgusting mess of pictures on top of each other. This may seem like a rather easy question, but how do I simply move the sprite 10 pixels!?

Comment: For a simple idea, check out [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443533/how-to-make-an-image-move-from-left-to-right-in-java/15443896#15443896)

Answer (score 3):

I see several problems in your code including:

- Getting your Graphics object by calling `getGraphics()` on a component. Note that this object won't persist.
- Drawing directly in the JFrame
- Not drawing in the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JComponent such as a JPanel
- Not calling the `super.paintComponent(...)` method inside of the `paintComponent(...)` method.
- Using a KeyListener instead of Key Bindings
- Not using a Swing Timer for the animation loop.

It looks like you haven't gone through the the tutorials on Swing graphics, and if so, I suggest that you do so without delay, you can also check out the many examples of how to do animation to be found on this site, some of which have been created by me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem succinctly, what's happening is that you aren't redrawing anything, per se. You're just drawing the new image on top of the old one, and graphics stay across redraw cycles.

Just do something like:

g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

right before you draw the image. Change the color to the JFrame's background color to make it look seamless (I think it's just getBackgroundColor()). Still, you should get a good book on Swing.

Comment: Also, BufferedImage s are a lot easier to handle and give you a lot more functionality than ImageIcons. Use the ImageIO class to load a bufferedimage in from a file.