# Drawing a class that extends JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, paint

I have a class that extends JPanel, it contains a draw(Graphics page) method to draw itself.. if I am building a test driver and want to display it on the frame what should I use.. I'm confused between paint(), paintComponent(), getGraphics() etc..

The Class

```
class Car extends JPanel {

     void draw (Graphics page) {
         ....draw polygons...
     }
```

****EDIT****

The goal is to animate the car moving across the screen, I changed the draw method to 'paintComponent()' and it showed up! But it needs to move it and repaint it with a timer. So I guess painting it over and over again is the reason it's draw() not paintComponent(). ?

Comment: Read the [Swing Painting Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) -- it's all there. You can also search this site for examples as it abounds with them, some written by me. And then please come back with a specific answerable question if you're still stuck.

Comment: Start with [Performing Custom Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), then take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and because you're clearly not confused enough, take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: You should be overriding `paintComponent`, but you SHOULD NOT BE CALLING IT MANUALLY!

Comment: The goal is to paint an instance of the class provided.. supposedly as is, I think thats why I'm struggling..

Comment: You do not control the repaint process, get over it.  You can request that the component be repaint by calling, surprisingly, `repaint()`.  Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858623/how-to-use-a-swing-timer-to-animate/15859932#15859932)

Comment: And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443533/how-to-make-an-image-move-from-left-to-right-in-java/15443896#15443896) as well...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the help. Your ball example really helped.

Comment: @MBarnett Bouncing balls are good :D

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree... any color but blue that is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `paint()` 
  AWT containers (use Swing) & Swing top level containers such as `JFrame` & `JApplet` (don't paint in top level containers - add a `JPanel` or `JComponent`).  So basically, don't in this age change the method.
- `paintComponent()` 
  The vast majority of Swing components.
- `getGraphics()` 
  [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) (possibly being displayed in a `JLabel`).  That will provide a `Graphics` instance, but I prefer using [`createGraphics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics%28%29) for a `Graphics2D` instance (rendering hints are wonderful).